# How many calls to free() are needed for `pixel (*copy)[rows] = malloc(cols * sizeof (*copy))`

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free, c99

I have seen various suggestions to allocate 2D arrays in C99 with expressions like this:

```
int (*array)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof *array);
```

I want to know three things:

1. Is the entire structure allocated on the heap? Or is this actually a bunch of pointers (on the stack) pointing to arrays on the heap..?
2. Is the allocated memory completely contiguous?
3. Is it true that only one call, `free(array)`, is needed to free the whole 2D structure? I read this somewhere - can't remember where - and it seems to work for me, but I'd like to understand why.

Comment: One `free`per `malloc`.

Comment: Although with C99's VLA (variable length arrays) you can have a local variable defined as `int array[cols]` where `cols` is a non-constant expression, `int (*array)[cols]` doesn't make sense at all.  VLA's cannot be dynamically allocated with `malloc`. They exist in automatic storage only (that which programmers commonly call "on the stack").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> (1) Is the entire structure allocated on the heap? Or is this actually a bunch of pointers (on the stack) pointing to arrays on the heap..?

The entire structure (everything that malloc allocates) is on the heap.

> (2) Is the allocated memory completely contiguous?

Yes, `malloc` allocates a contiguous region of storage.

> (3) Is it true that only one call, free(array), is needed to free the whole 2D structure? I read this somewhere - can't remember where - and it seems to work for me, but I'd like to understand why.

Yes, it's true. As to the *why* of it, why would it be any other way? You allocate a single region of storage using `malloc`, and `free` is used to de-allocate a single region of storage that was returned by a prior `malloc`.

I suspect you're confused by the declaration type, though you don't mention it:

```
int (*array)[cols]
```

This means that the `array` variable becomes a single pointer (which is itself allocated on the stack) to an array-of-`int` with `cols` elements (which is allocated on the heap due to the use of `malloc`). Compare this to the more common:

```
int *array[cols]
```

... which instead declares a 1-dimensional array of pointers (where the array itself will be on the stack). You might use this latter to create an array-of-pointers-to-arrays, by storing a pointer to a series of arrays in each element (arrays which you would indeed have to allocate and free individually!). This kind of construction can be used in a similar way to a 2D array, but is not really the same thing.

Remember also that a pointer in C can always point at an array. So, even though the first declaration declares a pointer to a 1-dimensional array, it can be used to point at an *array of* such arrays, i.e. a 2-dimensional array as you wanted. And indeed, the `malloc` call allocates storage for such an array:

```
malloc(rows * sizeof *array);
```

here, `sizeof *array` is the size in bytes of a (single) 1D array with `cols` elements. When multiplied by the number of rows, it yields the storage requirement of a 2D array with size `rows` × `cols`.

Comment: Thank you, my confusion was exactly because the more common type - int *array[cols] - requires a loop to allocate the inner arrays, and a corresponding loop to free them all (as Olaf elaborates in his answer).

Comment: @sacheie No problem. (I've since edited a similar elaboration into this answer).

Comment: It is not correct to make assumptions about where the malloc'd space is allocated in memory, it doesn't have to be on the heap. For example, GNU libc may mmap some memory if the malloc`d size exceeds some value.

Comment: @Ctx when GNU libc `mmap`'s memory to satisfy an allocation request you could consider that the memory obtained is part of the heap. IIRC Glibc in fact always uses `mmap` to extend the heap (though it may once have used the more traditional `sbrk` function to do so). Regardless, there is in my view little reason to distinguish between the cases of "allocated from a free list over memory which was originally allocated from the OS" compared to "allocated by requesting memory from the OS". Both cases require book-keeping on the part of the allocator.

Comment: @davmac The heap is still special in some ways. i.e. it is usually placed in the address space such that it can be easily extended (i.e. other mappings are avoided in the vincity of the heap). free()'d memory on the heap is usually not immediately returned to the os, in contrary to malloc()'d space which was mmap'd by the allocator. While I do agree, that the heap technically is "mapped memory" it is still used in a special way, other mappings can _not_ be seen as part of the heap.

Comment: @Ctx let's agree to disagree. Personally I think "the heap" just refers to the memory that is managed by the allocator, regardless of how it gets that memory and what it does when you call `free`.

Answer (score 2):

C does not do hidden memory allocation. The type in the question can be used as a true 2D array. Actually it is a "pointer to array[`cols`] of `int`".

OTOH, something like `int *array[cols]` (note the missing parenthesis) is not a 2D array, but an "array of pointers to `int`". Yet even here you have to `malloc` the array and each row explicitly!

And for every `malloc` you need a corresponding `free`.

Note that the C standard does not require a heap, stack or any other specific management structure. This is left to the implementation. However, most hosted environments (i.e. full-sized run-time) use something like a heap.

Remember to check the result of `malloc` and handle allocation failure appropriately.